# Android Facebook Login - Too many options

Tags: android, facebook

I want to create an Android app that uses Facebook to authenticate users, and later pass the access token to our web application server.

The app will only work once the user has been authenticated. So right when it starts I need to open a Facebook session, then use the access token and contact our own server for further information. The same Facebook session will then be used in the various app activities.

I can't make up my mind how to handle the Facebook session. Do I put one Login button as [described here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) in the first Activity? What do I do in other activities when the session state changes? I don't want to add a Facebook login to every activity...

Alternatively, I can use my own button, as shown in the SDK's Login Sample. But then I get the same management problems when the session is closed while I'm in another activity.

Or I can put everything in the same activity and use different fragments.

What's the best-practice way?

NOTE: Most of the SO questions on the matter are relevant to the older SDK (using the now deprecated `Facebook` class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is definitely to use a single Activity to handle all session state changes, and use that to drive UI changes. Android is pushing towards a Fragment model anyways, so I think that's your best bet.

Alternatively, if you need to use different activities, you can always use a common Session.StatusCallback implementation that has a reference to the current activity. Then you can create an intent to start a new activity if the state change drives a UI change.

Comment: I guess I can have just one Activity and shuffle fragments instead of switching activities. Is that really the way Android applications are headed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your facebook session like this

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(getActivity());
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }
```